# In BR-PT do people tend to avoid second person, personal pronouns the same way "tu" is avoided when referring to "you"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

I understand that generally "você" is preferred over "tu".

Does the preference for the third person also carry over to personal pronouns i.e. are "o", "a", "lhe", "se" preferred over "te"?

Comment: It depends on the region. In most dialects you'd hear in Brazilian TV and YouTube, *te* is more common than *o*, *a*, *lhe* for the second person. But, at least where I live, *se* is commonly used. Personally, I've never liked using *o*, *a*, *lhe* for *você*, I've just used it for the third person. By the way, I believe tomorrow you'll get more seen.

Comment: That's an answer, @Lambie.

Answer (score 3):

"tu" is used in some areas (north and south) and você in other places (for verb pronouns). se would only be used with reflexives verbs.

- Você foi a feira hoje? [Usually with pronoun but can be without it.]
- (Tu) Foste a feira hoje? [note the lack of a pronoun here.]

For example, "Eu **a vi** na rua". and "Eu **lhe disse** isso ontem." are said in "linguagem popular" (colloquial speech)

"Eu **vi ela** na rua." and "Eu disse isso **a/para você** ontem".

Also, the **te** is used for lhe or você: "Eu te disse isso ontem", even where the  você is being used by the person in his or her speech to address someone. **This usage is very colloquial and common.** One of the most common expressions: Já te falei isso. or "Já **te** disse isso. O que [é que] você acha?"

The **se** is used with reflexives in the third person: Ele **se cortou** com aquela faca que está na mesa. [se cortar=to cut oneself]

So to answer the question: Brazilians don't avoid the "tu" personal pronoun form of the verb. There are simply regions where it is used and regions where it is not used.